# Standardize the Home Page Link of other Stack Exchange Communities like in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design

Since I started to join other communities like Writing, English Language & Usage, etc. I always noticed something that made my UX a little bit confusing, the home page button redirects to Stack Exchange, not the current community.

In Stack Overflow, if I want to go back to the main page, I do click on the Home Page Link. For example:

[image: stack Overflow]

However, in other communities, it looks like this:

[image: English language and usage]

[image: Writing]

As a Stack Overflow user, I'm more inclined to do click on the StackExchange Logo by default. I always forget that the link in other communities doesn't have the same purpose.

I could suggest just a simple text like Writing for the button.

Comment: Yes, this trips me up each and every time I dare to venture outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: You seem to have the left navigation collapsed - in doing so, you get rid of the single-click to home page option.

Comment: Hi @Catija. I still considered it an improvement point.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of folks within Stack Overflow agree with you, and some of my fellow designers are looking at this. It can be tough to prioritize this work, but we see it as design debt at this point.

Each time I click the Stack Exchange logo I *expect* to be able to go back to Stack Overflow, or choose a different community.

Here’s a mockup of an approach we could possibly take here.

[image: Possible network-wide navigation]

Hopefully we can get some of this work prioritized in 2021 ✌️

Comment: Looks like it has be reviewed already, so [tag:status-planned] appears a better choice. No? :)

Comment: hmm not sure how I feel about this. One one hand it **does** make the ux more consistent, but on the other, it looks like we will need to use two clicks to get to the homepage.

Comment: There's still navigation underneath those popovers to get to all questions, say, within World Building.

Comment: ah you mean left nav? It would still need two clicks for those of us that have hide left nav enabled :(

Comment: This is a work in progress that is meant to illustrate that I agree with the question's premise that our information architecture could be standardized. I would accept another click if it meant a consistent experience across our products. I'm really not a fan of split dropdowns that save clicks by allowing a click-through on the left portion of the button, but a dropdown on the right portion.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation is a topic that our product and design teams are looking into. I've set the status to deferred for now as we don't have immediate plans yet. We'll revisit this when we do and provide more details when changes have been prioritized and/or completed.